# Why differing slope in geom_smooth depending on variable order in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, lm

When I plot my data in ggplot and add a regression line, I get differing slopes depending on which variable is defined as x and y. I expected the plots simply mirrored, but they aren't.
Am i missing something?

```
# create example data
v1 <- c(0.5, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.7, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.7, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7,
    0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.6, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6)
v2 <- c(0.6, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.3, 0.9, 0.7, 0.4, 0.7, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7,
    0.0, 0.5, 0.7, 0.7, 0.4, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.7, 0.4, 0.8, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6)
test1 <- data.frame(cbind(v1,v2))


# plot once with v1 as x and v2 as y and visa versa
ggplot(test1, aes(x=v1, y=v2)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(data= test1, method=lm,aes(x=v1, y=v2))  + 
  xlim(c(0,1))+ylim(c(0,1)) +
  geom_abline(col = "black")
```

[image: v1 vs v2]

```
ggplot(test1, aes(x=v2, y=v1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(data= test1, method=lm,aes(x=v2, y=v1))  +
  xlim(c(0,1))+ylim(c(0,1)) + 
  geom_abline(col = "black")
```

[image: v2 vs v1]

Comment: See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20553), the first answer giving a clear answer but that requires parsing some math, the second with a pretty quick visual intuition behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The short answer

When you call `geom_smooth()`, it calculates the slope of a simple linear regression (or OLS regression) of the form `y = a + bx`.

OLS is all about trying to come up with the best prediction of the `y` variable, given values of the `x` variable. This is a different goal than trying to come up with the best prediction of the `x` variable, given values of the `y` variable.

Hence, if you change the order of `aes(x = v1, y = v2)` to `aes(x = v2, y = v1)`, you're using `geom_smooth()` to accomplish two different, distinct goals.

#### Illustration

Imagine you have the following dataset:

[image]

When you run an OLS regression of `y ~ x`, you come up with the following model

```
y = 0.167 + 1.5*x
```

This optimizes predictions of `y` by making the following predictions, which have associated errors:

[image]

The OLS regression's predictions are optimal in the sense that the sum of the values in the rightmost column (i.e. the sum of squares) are as small as can be.

When you run an OLS regression of `x ~ y`, you come up with a different model:

```
x = -0.07 + 0.64*y
```

This optimizes predictions of x by making the following predictions, with associated errors.

[image]

Again, this is optimal in the sense that the sum of the values of the rightmost column are as small as possible (equal to `0.071`).

Now, imagine you tried to just invert the first model, `y = 0.167 + 1.5*x`, using algebra, giving you the model `x = -0.11 + 0.67*x`.

This would give you the following predictions and associated errors:

[image]

The sum of the values in the rightmost column is `0.074`, which is larger than the corresponding sum from the model you get from regressing x on y, i.e. the `x ~ y` model. In other words, the "inverted" model does a worse job than the simple `x ~ y` regression model.